# How to use the "result" and "loop" arguments in asyncio.sleep?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Extracted from [python 3.6.8 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.sleep).

> `coroutine asyncio.sleep(delay, result=None, *, loop=None)`
>
> Create a coroutine that completes after a given time (in seconds). If result is provided, it is produced to the caller when the coroutine completes.

**Question 1:** What does the 2nd sentence mean, i.e. "If result is provided, ....."? I don't understand how to use the `result` argument. Can an example be provided to illustrate it's use?

**Question 2:** When should the `loop` argument be used? Can an example be given also to illustrate it's use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't understand how to use the `result` argument.

`result` is simply the value that will be returned by `asyncio.sleep` once the specified time elapses. This is useful if you replace something that returns actual data with `sleep()`, e.g. for testing purposes, you can immediately specify a return value. For example:

```
data = await read_from_database()
...

if mocking:
    read_from_database = functools.partial(
        asyncio.sleep, 0.1, result='no data')
else:
    async def read_from_database():
        ... real implementation ...
```

> When should the `loop` argument be used?

The `loop` argument is, as of Python 3.7 [deprecated and scheduled for removal](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.sleep). It was useful in Python 3.5 and earlier, when the return value of `asyncio.get_event_loop()` wasn't guaranteed to be the currently running event loop, but an event loop associated with the thread. Since one can run multiple event loops during the lifetime of a thread, correct code had to propagate an explicit `loop` everywhere. If you were running in a non-default event loop, you had to specify the `loop` to `asyncio.sleep` and most other asyncio functions and constructors. This style is often encountered in old tutorials and is nowadays [actively discouraged](https://speakerdeck.com/1st1/asyncio-today-and-tomorrow?slide=14).

Comment: Noted that `loop` will be depreciated. As for `result`, am I correct that it's value can be any string or number that I desire to be returned at the end of 0.1sec in your example? That is, in your example, `read_from_database =  'no data'` if mocking is True after 0.1sec?

Comment: @SunBear That is correct, you can pass any object and it will be returned by `sleep()` unchanged, after the delay elapses. I'm not sure what you meant by `read_from_database = 'no data'`, but (after the await, and if `mocking` is true) it will hold that `data == 'no data'`.

Comment: I initially thought `read_from_database = 'no data'` because of `read_from_database = functools.partial(asyncio.sleep, 0.1, result='no data')`. Looking at it carefully, I realised `read_from_data` has actually become a pointer to `functools.partial(<function sleep at 0x7fbe4a604d90>, 0.1, 'no data')`  and since `data = await read_from_database()`, i.e. the execution of the pointer results in a `<generator object sleep at 0x7fbe49deb888>`, therefore data == 'no data' is True. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @SunBear Right, even with normal functions, `partial` simply returns another function, not actual data passed to the function. Here the idea is to make `read_from_database` a synonym for `sleep`. The same could have been achieved with `async def read_from_database(): return await asyncio.sleep(.1, result='no data')`, but then one could simply have `return 'no data'` after the `await` so it wouldn't demonstrate `result`. The `result` feature is not very useful when async/await is available to compose async code.